# paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Server connection dropped:

Tags: python, airflow, sftp, paramiko

While we are trying to download a file from one of the SFTP server job is getting failed with the below error.

```
**Error**
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Server connection dropped: 
/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/sftp.py
raise socket.error("Socket is closed")
OSError: Socket is closed
```

We do have multiple files available in the same path. (/adlsuser/fs/) we are able to download all the files except one file.

All the files are less than 100 mb but the file which are trying to download is of more than 500 MB. Any suggestion pls.

Comment: Are you using a library like pysftp, or your own code for downloading the file?

Comment: @NickODell we are using own code : but similar to https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-sftp/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/sftp/operators/sftp.html#SFTPOperator.execute

Comment: That code seems to call out to airflow.providers.sftp.hooks.sftp.SFTPHook in order to actually transfer the file. Is your code the same way? If so, might be good to tag this with airflow, and get someone who's familiar with airflow internals.

Comment: @NickODell . By picking this example : We have created a custom operator to do SFTP between the servers. I have tagged airflow as well. Could you please help with any suggestion why we get this error as we are not facing this error for any other files..

Comment: @Shashwat Hi Shashwat : no we are still facing the issue

Comment: @Arya Did you try passing the timeout parameter when creating a connection?